# paypal ipn no longer working

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I tried finding an answer here but can not.

I've been using this code to process PayPal IPN for over a decade!  Now, as of July 2018 it no longer works!

> https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/asp/paypal_ipn.asp

The only thing I know that is different recently is that PayPal required my domain to use TLS 1.2.  I asked my hosting company to make sure that it now uses that, and they made some change to make sure.  Ever since then, the listener I have set up does not process the IPN correctly. The code always falls into this IF:

```
if (objHttp.status <> 200 ) then
```

And never falls into this ELSEIF the way it used to when it was working fine:

```
elseif (objHttp.responseText = "VERIFIED") then
```

I'm not even sure how to troubleshoot this at this point.  Is it something about the TLS 1.2?  How can I make sure my hosting company set that up correctly?

Does my listener have to be located at an HTTPS url on my site? (Right now it is on HTTP).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In February, I got an email notice from Paypal that IPN would no longer validate successfully via an HTTP callback, and would further require HTTPS/SSL to validate. Update your script to connect this way, and it will probably fix it.

This PHP example should give a reasonable example.

Line 142:
"       $fp = fsockopen("ssl://www.paypal.com",443,$err_num,$err_str,30);"

I had similar issues previously when connecting to Paypal on port 80.